# Scan for changed files

Tags: c++, windows, git, backup

I'm looking for a good efficient method for scanning a directory structure for changed files in Windows XP+. Something like how git does it is exactly what I'm looking for, when running a `git status` it displays all modified files, all new (untracked) files and deleted files very quickly which is exactly what I would like to do.

I have a basic model up and running which performs an initial scan and stores all filenames, size, dates and attributes.

On a subsequent scan it checks if the size, attributes or date have changed and marks as a changed file.

My issue now comes in detecting moved and deleted files. Is there a tried and tested method for this sort of thing? I'm struggling to come up with a good method.

I should mention that it will eventually use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to monitor files and alert the user when something changes so a full scan is really a last resort after the initial scan.

Thanks,
J

EDIT: I think I may have described the problem badly. The issue I'm facing is not so much detecting the changes - I have `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` using IOCP on multiple threads to detected when a change happens, the issue is more what to do with the information. For example, a moved file is reported as a delete followed by a create and a rename comes in 2 parts, old name, followed by new name. So what I'm asking is how to differentiate between the delete as part of a move and an actual delete. I'm guessing buffering the changes and processing batches would be an option but feels messy.

Answer (score 3):

In native code `FileSystemWatcher` is replaced by [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Using this properly is not simple, there is a good baseline to build off [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/directorychangewatcher.aspx).

I have used this code in a previous job and it worked pretty well.  The Win32 API itself (and `FileSystemWatcher`) are prone to problems that are described in the docs and also discussed in various places online, but impact of those will depending on your use cases.

EDIT: the exact change is indicated in the [FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364391%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure that you get back - adds, removals, rename data including old and new name.

Comment: Gack. Essentially the same as my answer, posted while I was composing it. You get +1 though for obvious genius. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm actually using the API already but I've edited the question to clarify the problem I'm having.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I know this API well after trying to build a 100% reliable change detection scheme - it's not easy and we never worked out all the problems though it was 99.99% correct.

Comment: @user290796 - you can't detect adds/removes after the fact, you need some scheme to track this from the time the directory is created. `git` and source code control systems put the "baseline" information in place when the target filesystem is first modified by them, and then use this to reconcile later changes and file deletion and addition (a rename can be essentially handled as an atomic delete-and-add).  For realtime change detection I can't think of a better way than the Win32 API I noted here.

Answer (score 2):

I voted Liviu M. up. However, another option if you don't want to use the .NET framework for some reason, would be to use the basic Win32 API call [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use USN journaling if you are up to it, that is pretty low level (NTFS level) stuff.

[Here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/blog/1017/entry-2579-stcroixskippers-usn-journal-explorer-v12/) you can find detailed information and source code included. It is written in C# but most of it is PInvoking C/C++ functions.

Comment: Thanks but the FileSystemWatcher component is .NET and I'm using Win32 API. I have no problem detecting the changes using the `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` function, my issue is really detecting whether a file is deleted or moved or renamed etc. I'm hoping there is a tried and tested method for scanning for changes that I haven't found so far..

Comment: BTW I am not making marketing for that app I just consider it to be a good example on the issue you are facing.